# Is it possible to run an ' HAS ANCESTOR' filter/query on a property that contains a list(Value) of keys

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I have a kind `client` that consists of entities with a property `psets` containing a list of `Key`

Using the JSON api `psets` this would expressed as :

```
psets = { listValue: [ {keyValue: { path: [...]} },{keyValue: { path: [...]} },... ]}
```

The KeyValues are made of `path = [{ kind: 'project', name: 'projectn' }]`

I am trying to run an 'ancestor' query on 'client' using

```
SELECT * from client where psets HAS ANCESTOR KEY( project, 'project1')
```

This query returns an error: `unsupported property`

What is unsupported ?

How can I run an 'HAS ANCESTOR' filter on a list of Keys ?

Please note that according the the [DataStore Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/apis/gql/gql_reference) (Operators and comparisons)

> A condition can also test whether one entity has another entity as an ancestor, using the HAS ANCESTOR or HAS DESCENDANT operators. These operators test ancestor relationships between keys. They can operate on __key__, but **they can also operate on a key-valued property**. For HAS ANCESTOR, the right operand cannot be a property

(emphasis mine)

Comment: This looks like a documentation bug. I'm working on getting that fixed and hopefully providing a better error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datastore only supports the `HAS ANCESTOR` operator on entity keys (i.e. the special `__key__` property), not on regular key values.

A possible workaround would be to explicitly include each of the ancestors as a property in the entity.

So for example, if your `psets` property contained a key `project:project1/foo:2/bar:3`, you could maintain a separate `psets_ancestors` list property that contained `project:project1`, `project:project1/foo:2`, and `project:project1/foo:2/bar:3`. Then you could do equality queries on the `psets_ancestors` property:

`SELECT * FROM client WHERE psets_ancestors = KEY(project, 'project1')`

(This comes at the cost of extra index entries and having to maintain the separate list property.)